# Positioning elements in one row without flexbox

Tags: html, css, display

I need to have Element A next to Element B in one row so that element B and its border-bottom spans the entire space left and the width of element A is not known upfront.

I've tried using `display: inline-block` on B but then it pops into next line and with just `display: inline` I cannot have its bottom margin span to the right of the screen

Codepen enclosed: https://codepen.io/bbluszcz/pen/Xyywqx?editors=1100

**Important: for some reasons I cannot use flexbox**

```css
.a {
  display: inline;
  padding: 4px;
}

.b {
  display: inline-block;
  /*       display: inline; */
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed green;
}
```

```html
<div class="a"> Element A :</div>
<div class="b"> Element B </div>
```

Comment: I assumed you meant you needed Element A next to Element B, not "element B next to Element B". Feel free to rollback the change if I changed the intent of your question.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are using i.e. if you are styling a container with a grid, and  you want to style the div that is inside the container that has an image or icon. For example:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "left left right" "left left right" "bottom bottom bottom";
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 12px;
}

.left {
  grid-area: left;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 110px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="row">
      <img class="one" src="https://via.placeholder.com/110" />
      <img class="two" src="https://via.placeholder.com/110/ddd" />
      <img class="three" src="https://via.placeholder.com/110" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an old fashioned `float: left`. Float is usually for insetting one item inside of another like this:

[image]

Its a nice solution in this case as it lets you keep the other div full width.

```css
.a {
  padding: 4px;
  float: left;
}

.b {
  padding: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="a"> Element A :</div>
  <div class="b"> Element B </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="a"> Element A :</div>
  <div class="b"> Element B </div>
</div>


<div class="wrap">
  <div class="a"> Element A :</div>
  <div class="b"> Element B </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="a"> Element A :</div>
  <div class="b"> Element B </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this, one of the easiest would probably just be to use a table.  Note the `white-space: nowrap` or multiple words will wrap to next line.

```
.a {
    padding: 4px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.b {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed green;
}
<table>
   <tr>
      <td class="a">  Element A :</td>
      <td class="b">  Element B </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer is almost good for me except that if i multiply the first elementns over next rows the table breaks in exacrly the same position.  https://codepen.io/bbluszcz/pen/Xyywqx?editors=1100 - here's the codepen illustrating my problem . So basically i I need element A and B start shortly after their respective descriptions...

Comment: Tables should only be used for tabular data (data that belongs in clearly defined rows and columns, not for layout. You could continue to use `div` elements, but use `display: table-cell` to create a similar look.